# PHP database application using XAJAX

Tags: xajax

I want to convert my normal database application to XAJAX application (without reload).
My application based on sending and reading data using GET and POST requests (After page load).

How can I pass data to url without refresh?

Example: I want to send the ID of the selected row on the table without the use of `<a href="index.php?action=edit&id='. $row['CountryID'] .'">`

Can that happend using the XAJAX?

And can I send Array in `$objResponse->assign("div", "innerHTML", $HERE);`?

Answer (score 1):

creates a function that receives the ID you're submitting. eg

```
function name_function($id){
     $response = new xajaxResponse();//to post the answer
     //what you do
     $response->assign("your_div","innerHTML",$variable_that_you_use);
     return $response
}
```